# setting <img> src attribute with path to JCR repository

Tags: java, html, jackrabbit, jcr

Is it possible to set the src attribute of img tag with path to JCR repository?
I want to generate html having img tags with their src attribute set with the path of JCR repository.

Comment: Can a browser access those files directly?

Answer (score 0):

Not with plain jackrabbit, but would be possible with Apache Sling infront.
Sling is a content centric restful webframework that allows to directly map URLs to jcr resources and directly integrates with jackrabbit.